# Do I still use the official documentation from seven years ago to partition a 2TB SSD drive for installing Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

Found an official Ubuntu documentation page from seven years ago about how to partition an empty 2TB HDD for installing Ubuntu. It offers the 4-partition scheme of four primaries: /boot (1GB), swap (4GB), / (30-50GB), and /home (50-100GB). Just wondering if this template still applies in 2023 with NVMe SSDs.

I essentially want to install 22.04LTS on a new HP ZBook Fury 17 G8 workstation laptop that has the following configuration: Core i9-11950H CPU / 64GB RAM / NVIDIA QUADRO RTX3000 Discrete GPU / two Samsung Pro 980 NVMe SSDs of 2TB each / one HP 1TB SATA SSD

I'm essentially wanting to know how best to allocate my space for a clean install of Ubuntu as the only OS, but keeping / on the first NVMe while placing /home on the second. This has always been my configuration for video editing, keeping the OS and apps on one drive while writing all data to my home folder on a separate HDD. Just wondering how this is done in 2023 with all SSDs. For what it's worth, I don't store any of my original video files or final edits internally. I'd be using the /home NVMe for scratch video editing only. Would appreciate any input anyone's willing to give me. Thanks much. Be blessed today.

Comment: Are you sure that Ubuntu is good for video editing? I think windows Is more suitable for graphic design in general

Comment: I personally see no need for a separate /boot partition. /swap is kind of old school, new installs use a swap file. So I have /home and / only. But that's just my opinion, and unfortunately your question is largely opinion-based.

Comment: The 4 primary partition limit was for old BIOS/MBR systems. Now you want UEFI install an use gpt partitioning. You need an ESP, FAT32 with boot,esp flags, / (root) as minimum. It will create a default swap file. If you have a swap partition it will use that and swap can be 4.1GB, as often suggested Do not hibernate. I typically keep /home inside / (root) but then have data partition(s) for data, some on same drive & some on second drive. And mount data partition(s) & link into /home. Not sure if works well with snaps, but I do not use snaps.

Comment: @oldfred: Yes, this sounds like a solid option. Q: Can you link me a guide or tutorial showing how to link my installation to a separate data partition? I think I followed your lead on this idea several years back with a UEFI desktop installation. Worked like a charm. Thanks all for the quick, thoughtful responses. Blessings.

Comment: I use /mnt/data, but many have posted probably better to just use /data. I did once mount something in /mnt & lost all my links until I rebooted. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2464944&p=14048909#post14048909  & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2315714
 I do not use snaps, and not sure if links work with snap apps.
 &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your question walks on the fence of a "opinion-based" question -

To eliminate opinions, It would certainly be best to follow the 22.04 [Installation guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) (Instead of depending on a document published seven years ago)

In the Installation guide, You have the option of "Manual partitioning" - You are the "Creator" and can pick and choose the "Mount points", "Filesystem type" and partition size you want for which devices.

If your choices don't meet your needs, no problem. You can always adjust the size of a [ext2, ext3, or ext4 file system](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-resize.html.en) So it will meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks much for this. Couldn't find the new installation guide for some reason. All is right with the world now. Again, much appreciated.